# SQL statement calculated field

Tags: mysql, sql, database

**This is my question, I need help with the last bullet point. I can't figure out how to create a calculated field that calculates what the field name suggests.**

From the City table select ID, name, Country and Population and from the Country table select Life Expectancy, Name, SurfaceArea, GNP. Restrict your result set using the following criteria( all of the following criteria must be met for records to be returned):

- Country SurfaceArea between 3,000,000 and 40,000,000 (using the
  between operator)
- The length of the City.District field is greater than 4
- Create the calculated
  field'CityPopulationPercentageOfCountryPopulation' that calculates
  what the field name suggests.

**This is what I have so far. Thanks in advance.**

```
SELECT City.ID
     , City.name
     , City.Country
     , City.Population
     , Country.LifeExpectancy
     , Country.Name
     , Country.SurfaceArea
     , Country.GNP
     , ROUND(City.Population * 100.0 / Country.Population, 1) AS 'CityPopulationPercentageOfCountryPopulation'
  FROM City
     , Country
 WHERE Country.SurfaceArea BETWEEN 3000000 AND 40000000 
   AND LENGTH(City.District) > 4
```

[Country table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Va8eV.jpg)

[City table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rwoUt.jpg)

Comment: Please share the list of tables and their structures

Comment: You should really use CHAR_LENGTH

Comment: Your calculation does exactly what you want, but you need to add a join between city and country.

Comment: seems like a semi-cross join here... every row returned from `City` matched with every row returned from `Country`.  I recommend ditching the old school comma syntax for the join operation, and use the `JOIN` keyword instead If we're intending a cartesian product, I'd recommend including the `CROSS` keyword to alert future readers that the omission of any conditions in the `ON` clause is intentional, and not an oversight. Also, `LENGTH` function returns number of bytes; use `CHAR_LENGTH` to return a count of characters

Comment: Use proper `JOIN`.  It's been around for over 20 years!!!

Comment: Thanks everyone, Im still new at this and I want really wanna learn because I enjoy it.

Answer (score 0):

*Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, standard `JOIN` syntax.  Your query should look like this:

```
 SELECT . . .
 FROM City JOIN
      Country
      ON City.CountryCode = Country.Code  -- or whatever columns are used for the `JOIN`
 WHERE Country.SurfaceArea BETWEEN 3000000 AND 40000000 AND
     LENGTH(City.District) > 4
```

Comment: is the ROUND() function i used correct for the needed question?

Comment: @user9893240 . . . That wasn't the problem with your query.  Does it return the value you expect?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a semi-cross join here. That is, every row returned from `City` is  matched with every row returned from `Country`.

I recommend ditching the old school comma syntax for the join operation, and use the `JOIN` keyword instead.  If we're intending a semi-Cartesian product, I'd recommend including the `CROSS` keyword to alert future readers that the omission of any join predicates (conditions to match on) in the `ON` clause is intentional, and not an oversight.

Also, the `LENGTH` function returns number of bytes; use `CHAR_LENGTH` to return a count of characters.

---

I suspect we want to "match" each City to a particular Country.  Maybe the `City` table contains a `Country_ID` column foreign key referencing `ID` column in the `Country` table. Or maybe the `Country` column is the foreign key. (That's just a guess; there's no conclusive indication this is the case in the question.)

```
SELECT ci.ID                   AS city_id
     , ci.name                 AS city_name
     , ci.Country              AS city_country
     , ci.Population           AS city_population
     , co.LifeExpectancy       AS country_lifeexpectancy   
     , co.Name                 AS country_name
     , co.SurfaceArea          AS country_surfacearea
     , co.GNP                  AS country_gnp
     , ROUND(100 * ci.Population / co.Population, 1) AS `CityPopulationPercentageOfCountryPopulation`
  FROM City ci
  JOIN Country co
    ON co.ID = ci.Country_ID
 WHERE co.SurfaceArea BETWEEN 3000000 AND 40000000
   AND CHAR_LENGTH(ci.District) > 4
```